# Relations between tables entity classes

Tags: java, database, jpa, entity, relationship

I have database like this:

I made entity classes for all of them but without relations, because I don't know how to do this. I know I should connect them by annotations `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` but dunno how. I mean, Order should have Person's list? Or just simple field?

Could you help me with this?

[image]

Comment: If you're using Netbeans you can generate your entity classes from the database. I assume Eclipse has this feature too. I do recommend learning how to manually associate entities, but generation is a good way to kickstart it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

Person:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="Person")
private Collection<Ordered> orders;

public Collection<Ordered> getOrders() {
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Collection<Ordered> orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}
```

Ordered:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;

public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}
```

Correct me if im wrong